# How to use $# in bool expression in bash?

Tags: bash

I trying to check range regarding to the `$#` in bash, but I get unexpected result.
I write the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# < 2 && $# > 3 ]]; then
   echo "error"
fi
```

And I trying to running the script such: `./s 1 2 3 4 5 6` but I don't get the "error" message.
What is the reason of that?

Comment: && means "and", a number can't be both less than two and greater than three

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are comparing strings, to compare integers you need an arithmetic expression `(( e ))`:

```
if (( $# < 2 && $# > 3 ))
```

Also, it's impossible for a number to be less than 2 **and** greater than 3, you meant *or*:

```
if (( $# < 2 || $# > 3 ))
```

Also, you don't need an arithmetic expression, you can use `-lt` (less than) and `-gt` (greater than):

```
if [[ $# -lt 2 || $# -gt 3 ]]
```